# android calendar change with device language

Tags: android, calendar

I'm stuck with one interesting problem.

I have a `Calendar` object with European style(? don't know how to call it right) i.e. week starts on Monday and ends on Sunday.

My issue appears when I change device language to English(U.S.). `Calendar` object changes its style to American i.e. week starts on Sunday and ends on Saturday.
Unfortunately I need week to start on Monday and end on Sunday but I can't understand how to do that.

I tried

```
calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
```

but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This maybe will help you
[Convert date from default locale to english locale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709894/convert-date-from-default-locale-to-english-locale)

Comment: This maybe will help you
[Convert date from default locale to english locale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709894/convert-date-from-default-locale-to-english-locale)

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help me(

Comment: I've found good explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522425/android-calendar-changing-the-start-day-of-week?rq=1